# Opening up a form in designer view does not show the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

## The wanted result:

I want to be able to edit a c# form in a designer view that resembles the following picture:
[image: Picture of drag and drop designer view]

## The Problem:

I created a default windows form C# program in VS.  When I right click Form1.cs and I choose [image: View Designer]

I am presented with [image: *this* page filled with code] instead of the expected drag and drop form editor.

## Other things I tried:

I tried pressing shift+F7 in the open form 1 but it brings me back to the page filled with code.

Does anyone know how to open the GUI drag and drop editor in VS?

Comment: [Introducing .NET Core Windows Forms Designer Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/) (09/30/2019)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi That link led me to the correct solution. I had created a C# program with the .net core insteac of the .net framework. The GUI editor is only available for the windows form applications created with the .net framework.

Comment: Yep, it happens. You see `Windows Forms App` and, well, just click it (it's the first one) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created a C# program with the .net core instead of the .net framework. The GUI editor is only available for the windows form applications created with the .net framework.

Thanks to @Jimi for helping me find the answer in the comments section.